# How to construct an [fromuri] method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

With the current method I am unable to get correct results from the following query string:
/api/data?name=STORM%202006-1%20A2&price_type=cvr

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<database_WICs> Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {


        var data = from c in db.database_WICs
                   where c.Name == query.name ||
                   c.CUSIP == query.cusip ||
                   c.ISINs == query.isin ||
                   c.Cover == query.price_type 
                   select c;
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

Is there a better way to implement this filter using linq query. If so, any examples would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a Model called Query and a API Controller called Data like below:

```
public class Query
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string cusip { get; set; }
    public string isin { get; set; }
    public string price_type { get; set; }
}

public class DataController : ApiController
{
    //GET api/Data
    public IEnumerable<database_WICs> Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {   
        var data = from c in db.database_WICs
                   where c.Name == query.name ||
                   c.CUSIP == query.cusip ||
                   c.ISINs == query.isin ||
                   c.Cover == query.price_type 
                   select c;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Your API GET method is fine, just delete "toList()". If you want it to return HttpResponseMessage, you can change it like below:

```
    //GET api/Data
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
       var data = from c in db.database_WICs
                           where c.Name == query.name ||
                           c.CUSIP == query.cusip ||
                           c.ISINs == query.isin ||
                           c.Cover == query.price_type 
                           select c;
        if (!data.Any())
        {
           var message = string.Format("No database_WICs was found");
           return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
```

But the problem is your URI is wrong. The URI should be like below:

```
/api/Data/?name=STORM&cusip=20&isin=2006-1%20A2&price_type=cvr
```

If you are passing JSON object to Web API via an AJAX call, the AJAX call should be like below:

```
var data =  {name:"STORM",cusip:"20",isin:"2006-1 20A2",price_type:"cvr"} ;
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Data/",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)         
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer and explanation. Apology to sound ungrateful, I would like to be able to call the query string as "api/data/name?=storm&price_type=talk". If possible, can this be achieved by executing this method in a Linq IF condition.

Comment: Hi, if I got right, you want to call the query string using LINQ.
LINQ is a language integrated query, not like AJAX you can pass the query string, it'll call the server side functions.

Comment: Hi Lin, I used you answer as framework to come with a solution to my query string issue.  I apologise if i was not clear in explaining my problem but your solution helped a lot.

Comment: Dear Lin, I would like to ask a little favor, regarding adding a 'Trim()' function to the name parameter but I can not get it to work.  for example i would like to trim name 'STORM 2012-2 A1' into 'storm' only. any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Instead of "Trim()", you can use "Split". For example, str.Split(' ').First().ToLower() will give you only lower case "storm".

Comment: Thank you. I shall give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to come up with a solution to search parameters such as name and price-type together using Lin's solution above:

```
        public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
        {
        var data = db.database_Dwic.AsQueryable();

        if (query.name != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Name.Trim() == query.name);    
        }

        if (query.price_type != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Cover == query.price_type);
        }

        if (!data.Any()) 
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data was found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        }
```